# Java: Remove all ArrayList<POJO>

Tags: java, list, arraylist, iteration, filtering

All,
  I'm trying to figure out what the most efficant way will be to remove items in a List which contains CSV information.  I'd like to use removeAll() but I'm not exactly sure how to apply it to this situation.

Take the following code as an example

Example Data:

```
Property 1 | Property 2 | Property 3
Foo        | Bar        | Data
Foo1       | Bar        | Data
Foo        | Bar1       | Data
```

Example POJO

```
public class MyPOJO {
  private String property1;
  private String property2;
  private String property3;

  public String getProperty1(){return property1;}
  public String getProperty2(){return property2;}
  public String getProperty3(){return property3;}
  public void   setProperty1(String property1){this.property1 = property1;}
  public void   setProperty2(String property1){this.property2 = property2;}
  public void   setProperty3(String property1){this.property3 = property3;}
}
```

Later, I'm parsing some CSV into this POJO and receive a set of filters via HashMap like the following

```
public class MyPOJOParser() {
  private List<MyPOJO> myPOJO = new ArrayList<MyPOJO>();

  public myPOJOParser(String flatfile, Map<String, String> filters) {
    myPOJO = parse(flatfile);  // Returns List<MyPOJO> 
  }
}
```

How would I do the following with the above examples

```
// filters contains 2 key value pairs:
// Property1,Foo1
// Property2,Bar
filters.forEach((k,v)->{
  // if(Property1 == "Foo1" && Property2 == "Bar") then remove all occurrences of this
});
```

Comment: `MyPOJOParser`'s overloaded constructor should be `public MyPOJOParser`. Also your comment `// if (Property1 == "Foo1" ...` may just be pseudo code but if you're checking for object equality then you should use `.equals(...)` not `==`.

Comment: You might use stream().filter(...).collect(Collectors.toList())